# How to write regex to match anything or nothing except certain character

Tags: regex

I have a regex which is \$[A-a]+[0-9]+ to match the strings like:
$A1 + $A10 to filter "$A1" and "$A10".

But if there is ":" before or after I don't want anything to be matched. Say, if the string is $A1:$A10. I don't want either $A1 or $A10 can be filtered.

How should I write the regex. I tried to use [^:] , which will be like:
[^:]\$[A-a]+[0-9]+[^:]
It seems string "$A1:$A10" works. (Nothing matched)
But then string "$A1+$A10" doesn't work. (Neither $A1 nor $A10 is matched)

Comment: Check the answer given by @Mischa which should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want zero-length lookahead and look behind patterns:

`(?<!:)\$\a+\d+(?!:)`

## Demo